# Nagios - Notifications - Not sending

Tags: nagios

please help me with Nagios and notifications.

In my service configuration i specify "contacts" . This contact i have specified in contacts.cfg

And there is problem, notifications wont come.

Please help me, why notification does not come to dominik and dominik1 ?

Thank you

There is my host.cfg

```
    define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       MySERVER
        service_description             PING
        check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        contacts                        dominik, dominik2
        notification_interval                 1
}
```

There is my contacts.cfg

```
 define contact{
        contact_name                    dominik            
        use                             generic-contact         
        alias                           Dominik            

        email                           dominik@dominik.com     
        }

define contact{
        contact_name                    dominik1            
        use                             generic-contact         
        alias                           Dominik1          

        email                           dominik1@dominik.com      
        }
```

There is my template.cfg

```
define service{
        name                            generic-service         ; The 'name' of this service template
        active_checks_enabled           1                       ; Active service checks are enabled
        passive_checks_enabled          1                       ; Passive service checks are enabled/accepted
        parallelize_check               1                       ; Active service checks should be parallelized (disabling this can lead to major performance problems)
        obsess_over_service             1                       ; We should obsess over this service (if necessary)
        check_freshness                 0                       ; Default is to NOT check service 'freshness'
        notifications_enabled           1                       ; Service notifications are enabled
        event_handler_enabled           1                       ; Service event handler is enabled
        flap_detection_enabled          1                       ; Flap detection is enabled
        process_perf_data               1                       ; Process performance data
        retain_status_information       1                       ; Retain status information across program restarts
        retain_nonstatus_information    1                       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
        is_volatile                     0                       ; The service is not volatile
        check_period                    24x7                    ; The service can be checked at any time of the day
        max_check_attempts              3                       ; Re-check the service up to 3 times in order to determine its final (hard) state
        normal_check_interval           10                      ; Check the service every 10 minutes under normal conditions
        retry_check_interval            2                       ; Re-check the service every two minutes until a hard state can be determined
 #       contact_groups                  admins                 ; Notifications get sent out to everyone in the 'admins' group
        notification_options            w,u,c,r                 ; Send notifications about warning, unknown, critical, and recovery events
        notification_interval           60                      ; Re-notify about service problems every hour
        notification_period             24x7                    ; Notifications can be sent out at any time
         register                        0                      ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL SERVICE, JUST A TEMPLATE!
        }
```

FOR sure i add also template for generic-contact

```
define contact{
        name                            generic-contact         ; The name of this contact template
        service_notification_period     24x7                    ; service notifications can be sent anytime
        host_notification_period        24x7                    ; host notifications can be sent anytime
        service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s             ; send notifications for all service states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
        host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s               ; send notifications for all host states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
        service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email ; send service notifications via email
        host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email    ; send host notifications via email
        register                        0                       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL CONTACT, JUST A TEMPLATE!
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be about the configurations. Just check if their is an email(SMTP) server up and running on your setup. Or add an external SMTP details in Nagios, so that Nagios would be able to send mails.